# Building SPA with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a login screen. Once login is successful, then I have to open a home page with bootstrap navigation. I have several links in the navigation.

Please suggest me,

1. How to use and configure 'browserouter'
2. how to enable/disable homepage when login is successful.

Sorry, I have trouble starting out where to write what.

Comment: Based on successful login, add Routes

Comment: how to enable/disable/redirect the login success to homepage?

Comment: check auth and route(from login) on successful login and redirect to homepage. Do it on `componentDidMount` of login page

Comment: Do you have a routes defined ?

Comment: Hi, where do I define the routes? can you give me step by step challenge?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly you are using react-router. This is the basic premise around client-side authentication. You should have some sort of state which indeed tells the app the user is logged in. With redux you would save a JWT or cookie in the global state. Then once the user visits the page you would based on the credentials:

- 1) Redirect the user from login page to home page if he is logged in:
  With react-router you would do that with:

  this.props.history.push('/')
- 2) Redirect the user from an unauthorized route (something like user profile page) to the login page:

  this.props.history.push('/login')

Keep in mind these are just guidelines and you would implement this based on your application, but essentially you should have everything thought out before doing so.

Hopefully this all helps!

Comment: Thanks.How to do I redirect from login page to home page after successful login? ( Hope the same login and home page is in SPA)

Comment: It depends on your backend. You should check if input fields match what is on the backend (if created properly it should also match the CSRF token). You can send an action with redux or you could use the `history.push` method i described inside the onSubmit prop.